# How to use MyBatis to connect to SQLserver in eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, model-view-controller, mybatis

Because I started learning SQLserver, I want to use SQLserver as the database of the project, but when I use mybatis to configure the data source, I don't know how to choose the data driver.
So I want to know if SQLserver can connect to SSM projects?

I want to use SQLserver as the database of spring+springMVC+mybatis project. What should I do?

```
--This is db.properties
jdbc.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=test
--This is applicationContext.xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
```

Comment: It is not clear what problem you get. Doesn't the configuration you has provided work? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I use a separate xml file to configure the mybatis settings like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
    <settings>
        <!-- changes from the defaults -->
       <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
       <!-- Mybatis logging -->
<!--        <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J2"/> -->
    </settings>
    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.mydomain.package"/>
    </typeAliases>
    <environments default="development">
      <environment id="development">
         <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
               <property name="driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
               <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;DatabaseName=test"/>
               <property name="username" value="username"/>
               <property name="password" value="password"/>
            </dataSource>
      </environment>
   </environments>

   <mappers>
      <mapper resource="mappers/ExampleMapperFile.xml"/>

   </mappers>
</configuration>
```

This is then referenced in application.properties:

```
mybatis.config=classpath:MybatisConfig.xml
```

Additional mybatis properties are:

```
#mybatis.mapperLocations=classpath*:**/mappers/*.xml
#mybatis.typeAliasesPackage=com.mydomain.package
#mybatis.typeHandlersPackage=handler's package
#mybatis.check-config-location=check the mybatis configuration exists
#mybatis.executorType=mode of execution. Default is SIMPLE
```